# CSS Flex Grid: matching image heights of different aspect ratios?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an example of a flex grid below. It takes 2 types of images, one a square and another a 16/9 rectangle.  As you can see from the demo below, the heights dont match up due to the different aspect rations.  Is there a way to "match" heights and maintain the aspect ratios?  Or is this not possible?
Ideally, setting a max height would be great and have the width auto adjust based on that but I can't seem to get that working.

```css
.root {
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 1200px;
}
.container {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   width: 100%;
   padding-left: -10px;
   padding-right: -10px;
}

.box1 {
   max-width: 200px;
   flex: 1 0 23%;
   padding: 10px;
}
.box2 {
   max-width: 300px;
   flex: 1 0 33%;
   padding: 10px;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">

  <div class="container">
      <div class="box1">
         <img src="https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/IeNJWoKYx1waOhfWF6TiuSiWBLfqLb18lmZYXSgsH1fvb8v1IYiZr5aYWe0Gxu-pVZX3=s180-rw"/>
      </div>
      <div class="box2">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/80/Aspect_ratio_-_16x9.svg/1200px-Aspect_ratio_-_16x9.svg.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="box1">
         <img src="https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/IeNJWoKYx1waOhfWF6TiuSiWBLfqLb18lmZYXSgsH1fvb8v1IYiZr5aYWe0Gxu-pVZX3=s180-rw"/>
      </div>
      <div class="box1">
         <img src="https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/IeNJWoKYx1waOhfWF6TiuSiWBLfqLb18lmZYXSgsH1fvb8v1IYiZr5aYWe0Gxu-pVZX3=s180-rw"/>
      </div>
      <div class="box1">
         <img src="https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/IeNJWoKYx1waOhfWF6TiuSiWBLfqLb18lmZYXSgsH1fvb8v1IYiZr5aYWe0Gxu-pVZX3=s180-rw"/>
      </div>
      <div class="box1">
         <img src="https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/IeNJWoKYx1waOhfWF6TiuSiWBLfqLb18lmZYXSgsH1fvb8v1IYiZr5aYWe0Gxu-pVZX3=s180-rw"/>
      </div>    
      <div class="box1">
         <img src="https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/IeNJWoKYx1waOhfWF6TiuSiWBLfqLb18lmZYXSgsH1fvb8v1IYiZr5aYWe0Gxu-pVZX3=s180-rw"/>
      </div>
      <div class="box1">
         <img src="https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/IeNJWoKYx1waOhfWF6TiuSiWBLfqLb18lmZYXSgsH1fvb8v1IYiZr5aYWe0Gxu-pVZX3=s180-rw"/>
      </div>
      <div class="box2">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/80/Aspect_ratio_-_16x9.svg/1200px-Aspect_ratio_-_16x9.svg.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="box1">
         <img src="https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/IeNJWoKYx1waOhfWF6TiuSiWBLfqLb18lmZYXSgsH1fvb8v1IYiZr5aYWe0Gxu-pVZX3=s180-rw"/>
      </div>
      <div class="box1">
         <img src="https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/IeNJWoKYx1waOhfWF6TiuSiWBLfqLb18lmZYXSgsH1fvb8v1IYiZr5aYWe0Gxu-pVZX3=s180-rw"/>
      </div>   
      <div class="box1">
         <img src="https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/IeNJWoKYx1waOhfWF6TiuSiWBLfqLb18lmZYXSgsH1fvb8v1IYiZr5aYWe0Gxu-pVZX3=s180-rw"/>
      </div>
      <div class="box2">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/80/Aspect_ratio_-_16x9.svg/1200px-Aspect_ratio_-_16x9.svg.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="box1">
         <img src="https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/IeNJWoKYx1waOhfWF6TiuSiWBLfqLb18lmZYXSgsH1fvb8v1IYiZr5aYWe0Gxu-pVZX3=s180-rw"/>
      </div>
      <div class="box1">
         <img src="https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/IeNJWoKYx1waOhfWF6TiuSiWBLfqLb18lmZYXSgsH1fvb8v1IYiZr5aYWe0Gxu-pVZX3=s180-rw"/>
      </div>
      <div class="box1">
         <img src="https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/IeNJWoKYx1waOhfWF6TiuSiWBLfqLb18lmZYXSgsH1fvb8v1IYiZr5aYWe0Gxu-pVZX3=s180-rw"/>
      </div>
      <div class="box1">
         <img src="https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/IeNJWoKYx1waOhfWF6TiuSiWBLfqLb18lmZYXSgsH1fvb8v1IYiZr5aYWe0Gxu-pVZX3=s180-rw"/>
      </div>
       <div class="box1">
         <img src="https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/IeNJWoKYx1waOhfWF6TiuSiWBLfqLb18lmZYXSgsH1fvb8v1IYiZr5aYWe0Gxu-pVZX3=s180-rw"/>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I don't understand what is intended by giving box and box2 max widths if you actually want their heights to be the same, it is preventing the box2 image from getting 'full' height.

Comment: @AHaworth if there a single item at the very end and in a row all alone, I don't want it taking up a large size which is why I had the max-width...to avoid it getting overly large

Comment: But if you allow a square to go to 200px then you need to allow a rectangle to go to 200px * 16/9 to have the same height. I don’t understand the 300px which is stopping the rectangles taking the same height as the squares.